# Is there a way to create a pop up in Xamarin forms ( software pattern - mvvm), without using plugins?

Tags: c#-4.0, mvvm, xamarin.forms, plugins

I am trying to generate pop up to remind the user to submit or to do some other functionality.Does any one have an idea ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For my apps I use the **App.xaml.cs** class, here is an example I use to show a **ContentView** on top of a **ContentPage** if the direct content of the **ContentPage** is an **AbsoluteLayout:**

**App.xaml.cs**

```
        public static void ShowPopup()
        {
            //Get current Page, we assume it's a ContentPage
            var mainPage = App.Current.MainPage as ContentPage;
            //Get the content of that Page, we assume it's an AbsoluteLayout
            var current = mainPage.Content as AbsoluteLayout;
            //Add WaitPopup.cs as a child
            current.Children.Add(new WaitPopup());
            //Re-load the view
            mainPage.Content = current;
        }

        public static void RemovePopup()
        {
            //Get current Page, we assume it's a ContentPage
            var mainPage = Current.MainPage as ContentPage;
            //Get the content of that Page, we assume it's an AbsoluteLayout
            var current = mainPage.Content as AbsoluteLayout;
            //Remove the child from the AbsoluteLayout, in this example it will be WaitPopup
            current.Children.RemoveAt(1);
            //Re-load the view
            mainPage.Content = current;
        }
```

**WaitPopUp.cs**, I like to create the Popup using c#, but you can create a new .xaml file and show that instead if you wish.

```
public class WaitPopup : ContentView
    {
        public WaitPopup()
        {
            /* We assume we are adding this to an AbsoluteLayout */
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(this, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(this, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
            /*I add opacity so that it looks more like a popup,change background to Transparent if you want this to look more like a true pop up */
            BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            Opacity = 0.77;
            /* All of this content is optional, apply whatever you wish to your PopUp */
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                /* */
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                /* */
                Children = {
                    /* */
                    new Image {
                        Source = "logo.png",
                        Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
                        Margin = new Thickness(100,30,100,20)
                    },
                    /* */
                    new Label {
                        Text = "Espera...",
                        TextColor = Color.Black,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
                    },
                }
            };
            //Optional, do not use if you do not understand animations
            RotateLogo();
        }
        private void RotateLogo()
        {
            //uint duration = 10 * 60 * 1000;
            var sLayout = this.Content as StackLayout;
            var logo = sLayout.Children[0] as Image;
            logo.RotateYTo(4 * 360, 10000);
        }
    }
```

**Example .xaml file that will work with WaitPopup, remember, technically you can make this pop up compatible with any Layout, but for this example we are assuming every Page has an AbsoluteLayout as it's content, and that when we add WaitPopUp.cs, it is the second child in the Children array of AbsoluteLayout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="CALogin.Views.LoginPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CALogin.ViewModels">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:LoginViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="MasterLayout" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0">
            <Grid x:Name="MasterGrid" BackgroundColor="Gray">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!-- Place all of your normal page content here, inside this "MasterGrid" -->
                <!-- When you call ShowPopup(), WaitPopup will be added as the 2nd child of the AbsoluteLayout -->
                <!-- WaitPopup will fill and expand the entire screen, overlapping MasterGrid -->
            </Grid>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

If you want to add a ViewModel you can do so no problem with BindingContext in WaitPopup.CS

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to create popup without using plugins, I use Collectionview to create custom popup, and set isvisible as false default, you can take a look:

MainPage.xaml:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout
        Padding="0"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            BackgroundColor="Azure">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Medium"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Text="Xamarin Monkeys" />
                <Image
                    x:Name="imgMonkey"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    Source="a11.jpg"
                    WidthRequest="200" />
                <Button
                    Clicked="btnPopupButton_Clicked"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Text="Show Popup"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

        <!--  Popup Area  -->
        <ContentView
            x:Name="popupLoginView"
            Padding="10,0"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            BackgroundColor="#C0808080"
            IsVisible="false">

            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <StackLayout
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    WidthRequest="300">
                    <Entry Margin="20,20,20,10" Placeholder="Enter Username" />
                    <Entry Margin="20,0,20,0" Placeholder="Enter Password" />
                    <Button Margin="20,0,20,0" Text="Login" />

                </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>

        </ContentView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

private void btnPopupButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        popupLoginView.IsVisible = true;
    }
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

You can use Collectionview to create different popup in different contentpage.

Comment: I like this when possible, although this Popup can only be shown within the same page it exists.

Comment: @LISA, anything update? If my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Do you mean ContentView Or CollectionView?